# Get show status from a conversation in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I've developed a messaging extension for Teams and successfully sending card in a conversation. But I want a data for my Action Cards.

When a user sends an action card to another user, another user might not be online and my action card be "not seen" status. But I want a custom action for my card to be "seen" from other person (not sender) to get my action card's usage data statistics.

How can I get another person's uid and my card's id to match without clicking anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present we don't have the feature of knowing seen/unseen status of card/messages of others. Microsoft will always focus on customer’s feedback and experience, some new features would be added to the services based on customers' feedback in the future, we also recommend you give your new idea in [Teams User Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com).

Comment: Thank you for information, I'll add a comment for this feature to collect statistics about extensions.